# Put a subfolder onto a different server with CNAME

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cname

Here's the situation. Website.com is an ASP site which needs a blog that is to be Wordpress. So the website.com/blog needs to be hosted onto a php-friendly server. The company hosting the ASP site doesn't want to have anything to do with Wordpress so we have to use some of the shared hosting providers.

How do I have the Blog section placed onto an entirely different server? I've heard this is done with CNAME, but I've never used it. Most of the research I've done revolves around subdomains, but I need a subfolder mapping, and there's not much to read about putting subfolders onto different servers with a different IP and everything.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options:

1. you can bring the traffic to your own server and then redirect to
   the correct location
2. you can bring the traffic to your own server and then proxy it to the correct location
3. you can direct the traffic to the correct location either via full page or an IFRAME type mechanism

Each option has some benefits and drawbacks depending your devs knowledge level and your infrastructure. Regarding subdomains, you could use a combination approach where you, for example, use subdomain.yourdomain.com to point to a server instance (can be the same server or a totally different one) that maps the subdomain.yourdomain.com name to a specific path, usually via Host header.

Answer (score 0):

A CNAME is a function in DNS that says "Whatever thing you wanted to find for this name, use the same thing for that other name instead". When you're working with web stuff the "thing" in there is nearly always an IP address.

That is, what a CNAME can do for you is to say that when a user's web browser tries to look up the IP address for `website.com`, it will use the IP address for `someotherwebsite.com`. Note the total absence of anything web-related, like subfolders, in this. CNAMEs work on whole domain names, nothing else. Since you want to serve only a part of the stuff at a particular name from another server, CNAME cannot help you. CNAME is the wrong tool for you problem. Do not taunt happy fun CNAME.

In order to serve `website.com/blog` from another server than `website.com`, you pretty much have to do some sort of reverse proxying (where the ASP site's server relays requests between the user and the Wordpress server). It's probably easier and more robust to give the Wordpress site its own name (`blog.website.com` or something), and redirect to that from `website.com/blog`, but only you can know if that's politically possible in your case.